# Php - get_option - Search for specific Options

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am trying to search for specific options (my_option_…) and print them in rows.

I have been testing things for a while now and I cannot find a solution.
Using (search_terms=my_option_) seems not to work.

Is there an easy way to implement this?

```
    <?php
        add_option('my_option_1', 'Option 1');
        add_option('my_option_2', 'Option 2');
        add_option('my_option_3', 'Option 3');
    ?>

    <?php
        $option1 = get_option('my_option_1');
        $option2 = get_option('my_option_2');
        $option3 = get_option('my_option_3');

        if ( get_option('search_terms=my_option_')){ //???

            echo "Multiple Found!!";

            while(get_option('search_terms=my_option_')) {
               echo "options"; //???
} 
            }

        if ( get_option('my_option_2')){ 

            echo "my_option_2 Found!!";

            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Does not make sense? Did you add any option or do you want to get any built-in option?

Comment: the option are already in the database, check my last edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "
    SELECT option_name FROM $wpdb->options
    WHERE option_name LIKE 'my_option_%'
";

$my_options = $wpdb->get_col($query);

if(!empty($my_options)) {

    echo "Multiple Found!!";

    foreach ($my_options as $my_option) {
        echo get_option($my_option);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! the code is not working. Maybe because instead of "$wpdb" I have to put my own table? in mysql I can see the options are in "FROM  `mywebsite0_options` ". Or because I have to change "LIKE" to "LIKE%…%"?

Comment: try inserting `global $wpdb;` at the top of the code

Comment: Is there a way to show the name of the options instead of the values?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add option, the way is: `update_option( $option, $new_value )`
Please check the [URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option).

If you would like to get option value, you can do it as:

```
    update_option( 'my_option_1', 'my_option_1_value' );
    update_option( 'my_option_2', 'my_option_2_value' );
    update_option( 'my_option_3', 'my_option_3_value' );
                                
    if ( get_option('my_option_1')){
        echo get_option('my_option_1'); // option value will be printed i.e. my_option_2_value
    }
                                
    if ( get_option('my_option_2')){
        echo get_option('my_option_2'); // options value will be printed i.e. my_option_2_value
    }
```

If you have option in the database, you can find the value of options as:

`echo get_option('option_name');`

Hopefully, it can give you idea.

Comment: Thanks for that! what I am trying to do is to create a list of all the options the start with the name like my_option_